# How to leave private group on telegram with Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

The following code is for joining a group on telegram:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest(
        hash='A4LmkR23G0IGxBE71zZfo1'
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

How to leave that group after the work is done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`client.delete_dialog`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.delete_dialog)

```
await client.delete_dialog('username')
# can accept chat ID too
```